# How to use TraversableLike.to[Col] with Map?

Tags: scala

I have an immutable Map that I wanna convert to TrieMap. I tried:

```
val mm = Map(1 -> 100)
mm.to[TrieMap]
mm.to[TrieMap[Int,Int]]
mm.to[TrieMap.Coll]
```

None works. All complains `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap takes no type parameters, expected: one`

I understand we can use `fold` or `reduce`, or `TrieMap.apply` to convert, but I want to learn how to use `to[Col]` method. I tried to google it but it is hard to search because `to` is a very generic word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
val mm = Map(1 -> 100)
mm.to(TrieMap)
```

which outputs

```
TrieMap(1 -> 100)
```

Note use of parenthesis instead of square brackets. Also note this uses implicit conversion `toFactory`:

```
mm.to(toFactory(TrieMap))
```

[Implementing custom collections (SCALA 2.13)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collections.html) shows some usages of `to` operations.